# Correct syntax for SDelete to wipe free space on the disk?

Tags: hard-drive, wipe, sdelete

If I use this [syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete#using-sdelete):

```
sdelete64.exe -p 3 -c 1% C
```

...where:

`-p 3` sets number of overwrite passes to 3
`-c 1%` sets amount of space to leave free to 1%
`C` Specifies drive letter C:

... I get the error message:

> SDelete is set for 3 passes
> Cleaning disk C:
> **Error opening disk C:
>
> The system cannot find the file specified**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `C:` instead of just `C`?

Comment: I also doubt very seriously that you should include the percent sign with -c.  Percent sign is magic to cmd.exe.

Comment: I used `sdelete64.exe -p 3 -c 1% C:` before, and then the error message was `Error opening disk C::`

Comment: @David.P Give this a shot `sdelete -c1 -p 3 c:` and if there are still issue, run it from cmd elevated as administrator.

Comment: Ahh the documentation really is poor - it suggests a space between -c and percent but looks like there isn't a space. So -c1 is leave 1% disk space when writing the clear file?

Answer (score 1):

****1. First solution (failed)****

You were mislead by a weak Microsoft documentation:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete

Microsoft does not explain or gives an example how to state a drive letter.

Sdelete tried to delete a file named `c` on your current drive.

Try out adding `:` as requested by DavidPostill.

****2. Second solution proposal****

Hint: Free space is a property of a file system. A physical disk with no partion or volume on it has only `space` but no distinction between used and unused (free) space.

Remove all partitions from your target disk and read out the `physical disk number` in `disk management`. Run sdelete(64) using the `physical disk number` instead of the volume label.

Comment: I used `sdelete64.exe -p 3 -c 1% C:` before, and then the error message was `Error opening disk C::`

Comment: Could you reduce the parameters to a minimum like "sdelete64 -z c:"? Could you try the 32-bit-version of "sdelete"?

Comment: I added a second solution proposal.